# I want to put blank pages after title page, acknowledgement, abstract, ant etc

Tags: front-matter

I want to put blank pages after title page, acknowledgement, abstract, ant etc. and also I want to strat a new chapter in a right side page. my codes are below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{packs}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}   
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{chapters/ack}
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\listoftables
\pagebreak
\listoffigures
\pagebreak
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]
{
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par
}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}
\listofmyequations
\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{chapters/ab}

\pagebreak
\input{chapters/introduction}
\pagebreak
\input{chapters/aim}
and so on
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{href}
\pagebreak
\input{chapters/ap}
\end{document}
```

How can I do them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the traditional approach is to use a two-sided `\documentclass`...

Here is how I do it, with the `changepage` package and a few clever macros, `\gotooddpage` and `\finishonevenpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}% TO MAKE SURE CERTAIN THINGS START ON ODD PAGE #
% MACRO TO GO TO ODD PAGE, INSERTING "INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK" IF NEEDED
\newcommand\gotooddpage{\clearpage%
  \checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\blankpage\fi\clearpage}
% MACRO TO FINISH ON EVEN PAGE, INSERTING "INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK" IF NEEDED
\newcommand\finishonevenpage{%
  \clearpage\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\else\blankpage\fi}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{
  \clearpage
  \begin{center}
    {\textsc{\rule{0em}{4.5in}Intentionally left blank.}}
  \end{center}
}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\gotooddpage \textbf{\color{red}THIS SHOULD BE ON AN ODD PAGE.}
\lipsum[3-10]
\gotooddpage \textbf{\color{red}THIS SHOULD BE ON AN ODD PAGE.}
\lipsum[11-13]
\finishonevenpage
\end{document}
```

[image]